# Can not sync Java web app on Azure using OneDrive

Tags: java, azure, deployment, jetty

I have a Java web app that I want to deploy to Azure. I had a look at [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-java-get-started) tutorial and as I understood from it, what I basically need to do is in some way upload a ROOT.war file to the site/wwwroot/webapps/ directory, and jetty will take care of the deployment automagically. This works fine when I upload the file via FTP, however when I use OneDrive for synchronization, ROOT.war is uploaded but the deployment does not happen and I get a generic "This Java web app was deployed successfully but there is nothing here yet " page deployed to my web app. I don't think there's anything wrong with the folder structure in my OneDrive as ROOT.war does indeed get copied under /site/wwwroot/webapps/, it just doesn't get deployed.

So my question is, how does jetty actually deploy my Java web app to Azure, what is the protocol here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you want to do the deployment for your Java web app on Azure WebApps via sync content from OneDrive. So I think you need to refer to the offical tutorial [`Sync content from a cloud folder to Azure App Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deploy-content-sync) to know how to do it.

However, the tutorial just introduce how to configure `Deployment options` (the same as `Deployment Source` in the tutorial) on Azure portal, but not tell us the file structure & path mapping between Azure WebApps and OneDrive.

You can try to browse the url of Kudu tool `https://<your webapp name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` to access the file system of Azure WebApp.

Assumption that you had configured `Deploymen options` for OneDrive and `Choose Folder` like `web4pp`(my webapp name), it will create a folder with the same name in your OneDrive path `Apps\Azure Web Apps`. Then, the OneDrive path `Apps\Azure Web Apps\<your chosed folder>` is mapped to the Kudu path `D:\home\site\wwwroot`. Please see the figures below.

Fig 1. Configuration for deployment source from OneDrive
[image]

Fig 2. File structure on OneDrive
[image]

Fig 3. File structure on Azure WebApp Kudu tool
[image]

So for syncing a Java webapp, you need to create a folder `webapps` at the OneDrive path `Apps\Azure Web Apps\<your chosed folder>`, and put your `.war` file into the folder, then click the `Sync` button on Azure portal as below. The Java app will be sync up to Azure WebApp.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Actually this is what I was already doing. There aren't any problems getting ROOT.war uploaded to Azure, but jetty does not realize that there is a ROOT.war file under webapps and start deploying it. I know jetty is configured correctly because when I upload ROOT.war via FTP, it gets deployed after a few minutes and the web app works just fine.

Comment: @halileohalilei Please try to restart your azure webapp, or try to unzip the ROOT.war as a `ROOT` directory to directly sync up.